# moving from "My Location" and it gets back to "My Location" in mapquest sdk for android

Tags: android, mapquest

I followed the sample "Finding Your Location" in [this](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api/documentation) tutorial, and mixed it with routing snippet, but after loading the map and showing my location, when I touch the map and move to view other areas, after a seconds map gets back to my location, I meant it does not allow moving across map.

Would you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a tap listener to your MyLocationOverlay to stop following when the map is tapped:

```
            mMyLocationOverlay.setTapListener(new OverlayTapListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTap(GeoPoint arg0, MapView arg1) {
                    mMyLocationOverlay.setFollowing(false);                     
                }
            });
```

Comment: I solved it my not using the mapquest location detector and instead using android location manager.